# ansible template lookup uid gid

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to get access to the uid/gid for a given username from inside an ansible template? I have a list of usernames that are passed to the template task, and I need to insert the uid/gid based upon the username.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to do that in a template. The solution would be to perform the mapping in a task, create a new fact with the result, and pass that into the template.

Comment: Thanks @larsks this indeed worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`pipe` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/pipe.html#examples) actually uses your specific case in its example (shelling out to the [`getent` binary](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/getent.1.html)), but you can do it with `awk` if you don't have `getent`:

```
- debug:
    msg: User fred's uid is {{ lookup('pipe', "awk -F: '/^fred/{print $3}' /etc/passwd") }}
```